# Where to perform library initialization for System.loadLibrary?

Tags: android, android-ndk, initialization

I want to do some initialization job in library. Any clue would be great. thanks.

Comment: If you haven't found it already: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Answer (score 0):

A constructor of a global/static C++ object might be a good place (but don't forget about `extern "C"{}` around JNI methods in the .cpp file). The constructor, however, doesn't get a `JNIEnv` pointer and can't do anything with the Java world.

Alternatively, introduce a static native method in the class that does the `loadLibrary()` call, and invoke this method right after the `loadLibrary()` call. This is probably simpler - no need to go C++.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just found JNI OnLoad function. that's exactly what I want.

Comment: I vaguely recall having trouble with JNI_OnLoad() 1-2 years ago, around Android 2.x. Don't remember what exactly the trouble was, but test it carefully. Oh, and we say thanks by accepting the answer :)